# How to validate form Dynamically added?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which adds a line dynamically when click on add form.

```
<form class="address">
  <input type="text" class="add_name">
  <input type="test" class="add_zip">
</form>
```

When Clicked on lets say a button add address:

```
<form class="address">
  <input type="text" class="add_name">
  <input type="test" class="add_zip">
    //added line when clicked on btn
  <input type="text" class="add_name">
  <input type="test" class="add_zip">
</form>
```

I used following code

```
 $('.address').each(function(){
    var address_form = $($this);
    if(address_form.find('.add_name').val() == ''){
       //dosomething
     }else{
        console.log(address_form.find('.add_name').val());
     }
 });
```

lets say if I put both address only first address is shown and second one undefined.

Comment: @Teemu thats class name..

Comment: you need an outer global selector to find dynamically added elements.
Something like `$(document).find('.address').each(....)`  should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```js
$('button').on("click",function(ev){
  const inps=$(".address input").slice(0,2).clone().val("");
  $(".address").append(inps).append("<br>")
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="address"><input type="text" class="add_name" name="name[]"
  placeholder="Enter your name"><input type="test" class="add_zip" name="zip[]" placeholder="and zip code"><br></form>
<button>add fields</button>
```

I added a `name` attribute to your input fields. By doing this the data can be collected on the backend in suitable array structures for `name` and `zip`.